# ggplot: how to plot a stack bar plot with dodge position

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset like:

```
region country urban_rural treatment      potential
----------------------------------------------------
Africa  Kenya     1         chlorine       compatible
Europe  England   2         non_clorine    not compatible
Africa  Kenya     1         other          potential
```

And I want to make a figure like :

[image]

can anyone help with this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question/problem correctly. I made up some more lines of dummy data to get a nicer plots. The graphs can (and probably should) be further polished.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table) # for the dummy data read in from plain text

# reading in some dummy data I made up buy copy and pasting plus minor changes
df <- data.table::fread("region,country,urban_rural,treatment,potential
Africa,Kenya,1,chlorine,compatible
Europe,England,2,non_clorine,not compatible
Africa,Kenya,1,other,potential
Africa,Kenya,1,chlorine,compatible
Africa,Kenya,2,non_clorine,not compatible
Europe,England,1,other,potential
Europe,England,1,other,potential
Europe,England,1,non_clorine,compatible
Africa,Kenya,2,non_clorine,not compatible
Africa,Kenya,1,non_clorine,potential
Africa,Kenya,1,other,potential
Europe,England,1,chlorine,compatible
Africa,Kenya,2,non_clorine,not compatible
Europe,England,1,other,potential
Africa,Kenya,1,other,potential
Africa,Kenya,1,non_clorine,compatible") 


# one plot for Kenya with title and modified X axis label
df %>% 
  # build the counts to display in graph
  dplyr::count(region, country, treatment, potential) %>% 
  # filter Kenya 
  dplyr::filter(country == 'Kenya') %>% 
  # plot
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = treatment, y = n, fill = potential )) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  # visual enhancement
  ggplot2::ggtitle("Africa") +
  ggplot2::xlab("Kenya")
```

[image]

```
# fast way to plot data for all countries
df %>% 
  # build the counts to display in graph
  dplyr::count(region, country, treatment, potential) %>%  
  # plot
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = treatment, y = n, fill = potential )) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  # build the subplots from country variable
  ggplot2::facet_wrap(~country)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. But I want the x-axis to be multiple countries, and the treatment to be dodge position. I have edited the figure I want.

Comment: @YiruChen you could use my second example and just include a line to filter for region equals to Africa. dplyr::filter(region == 'Africa') %>% is the line you have to put before the first ggplot2 call (where now is written #plot)